# Чтения бинарного файла с определенной точки (C#)

Tags: c#, файлы

Каким образом можно начать чтение массива байт с определенной точки в заданном файле, например, если мне надо пропустить начало файла (гипотетический заголовок), или если я знаю размер файла, например 100Кб, то начать читать файл с точки 30Кб и закончить на 80Кб, т.е. взять отрезок данных в заданном промежутке.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream.position

Answer (score 0):

Примерно так:

```
var head = 1024 * 30; // 30 KB
var bufferLen = 1024 * 50; // 50 KB
var buffer = new byte[bufferLen];
int numBytesToRead = bufferLen;
int numBytesRead = 0;

using (var stream = File.Open(@"C:\temp.txt", FileMode.Open))
{
    stream.Seek(head, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    while (numBytesToRead > 0)
    {
        int n = stream.Read(buffer, numBytesRead, numBytesToRead);
        if (n == 0)
            break;
        numBytesRead += n;
        numBytesToRead -= n;
    }
}
// Далее обработка массива buffer
```

Comment: это все равно неверно

Comment: @Zergatul, так норм?

Comment: я только не уверен, всегда ли `FileStream` читает весь буфер, поэтому в моем варианте есть цикл на такой случай

Comment: @Zergatul, я проверил, считывает как надо

Comment: на отдельном примере с небольшим файлом может и считывает. Вот в msdn пишут: Реализация может вернуть меньше байтов, чем было запрошено, даже если не был достигнут конец потока. https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream.read?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8

Comment: @Zergatul, поправил в соответствии с доками Microsoft